# how to develop enum string parse extention method?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, reflection

i have a big problem i try to develop parse enum int value to string value. my reference articale is " http://weblogs.asp.net/stefansedich/archive/2008/03/12/enum-with-string-values-in-c.aspx" but i have more than one property 2 or 3 or 4 or 45 or 100000000 how to parse it? i writed some codes below : but null reference exception : Vals[j] = item.GetType().GetProperty(item.Name, BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Static).ToString(); HOw to solve it?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Reflection;

namespace EnumString
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            String[] str = UserType.Login.GetStringValue();
            //Console.WriteLine(UserType.Login.GetStringValue());
            Console.Read();
        }
    }
    public enum UserType : int
    {
        [StringValueAttribute("xyz", "test")]
        Login = 1
    }
    public class StringValueAttribute : Attribute
    {
        public string UserName { get; protected set; }
        public string PassWord { get; protected set; }
        public decimal Something { get; protected set; }

        public StringValueAttribute(string Username, string Password, decimal something)
        {
            UserName = Username;
            PassWord = Password;
            Something = something;
        }
        public StringValueAttribute(string Username, string Password)
        {
            UserName = Username;
            PassWord = Password;
        }
        public StringValueAttribute(string Username)
        {
            UserName = Username;

        }

    }

    public static class Extentions
    {
        public static String[] GetStringValue(this Enum value)
        {
            // Get the type
            Type type = value.GetType();

            // Get fieldinfo for this type
            FieldInfo fieldInfo = type.GetField(value.ToString());

            // Get the stringvalue attributes
            StringValueAttribute[] attribs = fieldInfo.GetCustomAttributes(
                typeof(StringValueAttribute), false) as StringValueAttribute[];

            // Return the first if there was a match.


            PropertyInfo[] pi = attribs[0].GetType().GetProperties();
            String[] Vals = new String[pi.Length];
            int j = 0;
            foreach (PropertyInfo item in pi)
            {
                 Vals[j] = item.GetType().GetProperty(item.Name, BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Static).ToString();
                j++;
            }
            // i dislike return values one by one : attribs[0].UserName 
            return attribs.Length > 0 ? Vals : null; // i have more values
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What differences would your string value function's behavior have from calling the Enum member's default .ToString() method?

Comment: i suppose he wants to get all duplicate values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if I understand correctly, you want to read all the properties of the attribute via reflection (instead of accessing them by name).
If so, your extension method should become:

```
public static Object[] GetStringValue(this Enum value)
{
    // Get the type
    Type type = value.GetType();

    // Get fieldinfo for this type
    FieldInfo fieldInfo = type.GetField(value.ToString());

    // Get the stringvalue attributes
    StringValueAttribute[] attribs = fieldInfo.GetCustomAttributes(
        typeof(StringValueAttribute), false) as StringValueAttribute[];

    PropertyInfo[] pi = attribs[0].GetType().GetProperties();
    Object[] Vals = new Object[pi.Length];
    int j = 0;
    foreach (PropertyInfo item in pi)
    {
         Vals[j] = item.GetValue(attribs[0],null);
        j++;
    }
    return attribs.Length > 0 ? Vals : null; // i have more values
}
```

Or (with a bit of Linq):

```
public static Object[] GetStringValue(this Enum value)
{
    // Get the type
    Type type = value.GetType();

    // Get fieldinfo for this type
    FieldInfo fieldInfo = type.GetField(value.ToString());

    // Get the stringvalue attributes
    StringValueAttribute[] attribs = fieldInfo.GetCustomAttributes(
        typeof(StringValueAttribute), false) as StringValueAttribute[];

    return attribs[0].GetType().GetProperties()
        .Select(p => p.GetValue(attribs[0],null))
        .ToArray();

}
```

note that you're returning an array of Objects, not strings, since in your attribute you have properties of various types.